# Library for parsing BibTeX

Tags: javascript, html, css, latex, bibtex

I am looking for Javascript library for parsing [BibTeX](http://www.bibtex.org/) files. Ideally, I would like to be able to cite papers and generate publication lists from BibTeX database (files with *.bib* extension). Any tips regarding what I should go with?

I am aware of [bibtex-js](https://code.google.com/p/bibtex-js/). Is there anything else available?

Answer (score 4):

I made a project, incidentally also called [bibtex-js](https://github.com/digitalheir/bibtex-js). Also available [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bibtex).

I made it because most BibTeX parsers out there take considerable shortcuts in parsing. This one aligns closely with the authoritative document on BibTeX, [*Tame the BeaST*](http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) and parses bibfiles into well defined objects.

Typescript types are included.

```
npm install bibtex
```

And then:

```
import {parseBibFile} from "bibtex";
const bibFile = parseBibFile(bibtexString);
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want the output to be. If you want to spit out JSON, then the definite go to choice is [bibtex-parser-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bibtex-parser-js). If you want to generate HTML rendered from the bib input, then there's a few options: [bibtex2html](https://github.com/backtracking/bibtex2html) (OCaml)
[bibhtml](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/bibhtml/) (XSLT)
[bib2xhtml](https://github.com/dspinellis/bib2xhtml) (Perl)
[bibtex2web](https://github.com/mernst/bibtex2web) (Perl)

...but they're not JavaScript. However, this might be useful for you: [bib-publication-list](https://github.com/vkaravir/bib-publication-list)